# Why do the infinitely many infinitesimal errors from each term of an infinite Riemann sum still add up to only an infinitesimal error?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, nonstandard-analysis

Ok, so after extensive research on the topic of how we deal with the idea of an infinitesimal amount of error, I learned about the standard part function as a way to deal with discarding this infinitesimal difference $\Delta x$ by rounding off to the nearest real number, which is zero. I've never taken nonstandard analysis before, but here's my question.

When you take a Riemann sum, you are approximating an area by rectangles, and each of those rectangles has an error in approximating the actual area under the curve for the corresponding part of the graph.  As $\Delta x$ becomes infinitesimal, the width of these rectangles becomes infinitesimal, so each error becomes infinitesimal.  But since there are infinitely many rectangles in that case, why is it that the total error from all of them still infinitesimal? In other words, shouldn't an infinite amount of infinitesimals add up to a significant amount?

Comment: I think there may be a fundamental misunderstanding in your question. You bring up the topic of nonstandard analysis, though the most common definition of the integral lives comfortably in the realm of standard analysis. Are you really looking for an answer which uses the concepts of nonstandard analysis?

Comment: @AntonioVargas maybe. I'm saying that, if I understand correctly, there's infinitesimal error that we round down to zero. But, it's the limit of a Reimann sum to an infinite term that defines the integral. The hyperreals are negligible for any finite summation, but I don't see how we can take the standard part for an infinite sum. So it's a question of how we justify real analysis knowing the non-standard analysis approach.

Comment: My point is that to define the integral we don't *need* to use hyperreals at all; they don't even need to be part of the conversation. All we need to do is take a *limit* of real numbers. So either you're asking about how that is usually done to define the integral, or you're asking about how one can use nonstandard analysis to define the integral (which is not the common way to do it, and possibly not an easy way to do it either).

Comment: @AntonioVargas you have a good point. I guess I want to understand why we don't need to consider the hyperreals in our definition in real analysis of an integral and derivative, even as fundamental as the limit. Because there's a paradox: the difference quotient is undefined when $h$ is zero. But we still say it's exactly zero. The only way I see that we justify this is through the standard part function.

Comment: Numbers such as slope and integral are defined to be the standard part of their hypperreal values. It's sort of like saying that the "real" world is a subset of the "hyperreal" world.

Comment: @StevenGregory yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. I see standard part as roundoff, and there's an infinite amount of infinitesimal roundoff with a the standard part of a infinite Riemann sum, which I feel like must sum to a non-negligible amount.

Comment: When you talk about "error", what are you comparing that error to?  That is, what is the "correct answer" from which the error is deviating?

Comment: @EricWofsey from $h$ or $\Delta x$ being *exactly* zero, or, the exact area under a curve.

Comment: It seems to me that you would be best served by simply learning about the usual "epsilon-delta" definition of a limit of real numbers. No hyperreals, no magic :)

Comment: But what do you mean by "the exact area under the curve"?  In the context of nonstandard analysis, taking the standard part of a hyperfinite Riemann sum is how you _define_ "area under the curve".

Comment: everything is here [wiki/Hyperreal_number#Calculus_with_algebraic_functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number#Calculus_with_algebraic_functions) ? maybe you'll also have to prove the hyperreal fundamental theorem of calculus, for using it in practice

Comment: @user1952009 so I'm referring to this link that you provided. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number#Integration and I can't see how the *dx* from an infinite sum can still be considered zero, as we round off to zero with the standard part.

Comment: the rule is that $st(x+y dx^k) = x$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k > 0$, and with the lower and upper bound of the integral $\int_a^b x dx$ you get a sum which is between $\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}-dx$ and $\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}+dx$ hence $st(\int_a^b x dx)  = \frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$

Comment: The error *vanishes* in taking the limit. That is the key point. If you are having difficulty understanding that, then it might help you to talk briefly about topology and the notion of neighborhoods (open sets containing a given point) and how that relates to limits and convergence.

Comment: I'm going to ignore nonstandard analysis. By basic geometry, any finite Riemann sum, as an approximation for signed area between the graph of a (let's say continuous) function and the x-axis, has discrepancy bounded by a bunch of rectangles with error $\le\sum |\Delta f(x_i)|\Delta x_i\le \max_i |\Delta f(x_i)|\cdot (b-a)$. On a compact interval $[a,b]$ at least, $f$ is uniformly continuous, hence one can bound $\max_i |\Delta f(x_i)|$ below any chosen $\varepsilon>0$ for sufficiently small mesh. Hence the Riemann sum converges to the correct signed area as mesh tends to zero.

Comment: I have rewritten the question to try to make it clearer.  Feel free to revert or further edit if I haven't stated the question exactly the way you meant it.

Comment: @EricWofsey it is perfect the way you edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, here is a heuristic explanation.  Note that this is *not* rigorous, since to make your question rigorous you have to give some precise definition of what you mean by "the exact area", which is not at all easy to define in general.

Let us assume we are integrating a continuous function $f(x)$ from $0$ to $1$ by using a Riemann sum with infinitesimal increment $\Delta x$.  Let us also assume for simplicity that $f$ is increasing (the general case works out essentially the same way but is a little more complicated to talk about).  So we are approximating "the area under $f$" by replacing the region under the graph of $f$ from $x=c$ to $x=c+\Delta x$ by a rectangle of height $f(c)$, for $1/\Delta x$ different values of $c$.  Now since $f$ is increasing, the difference between our rectangle of height $f(c)$ and the actual area under the graph of $f$ from $c$ to $c+\Delta x$ is at most $\Delta x(f(c+\Delta x)-f(c))$.  But since $f$ is (uniformly) continuous, $f(c+\Delta x)-f(c)$ is infinitesimal.  So our error is an infinitesimal quantity times $\Delta x$.

So although we are adding up $1/\Delta x$ (an infinite number) different errors to get the total error, each individual error is not just infinitesimal but infinitesimally *smaller* than $\Delta x$.  So it is reasonable to expect that the sum of all of the errors is still infinitesimal.

Comment: This makes so much sense! Thank you! Why is this explanation not used often in talking about integration in real analysis? I've done much research and haven't seen it explained as such before.

Comment: I think that many people get it drilled into their head early on that Riemann sums can approximate areas, so it doesn't even occur to them to question this.

Comment: well thank you for making it easy to understand. I just have one question about what you said. You said that because $f$ is continuous, $f(c+\Deltax)-f(c)$ is infinitesimal. It does make intuitive sense, but could you explain it a bit more? Is it because for a given $\Deltax$ then it can only grow at most $c\Deltax$ where $c$ is a finite constant; and a finite constant times an infinitesimal is still infinitesimally small? I don't quite understand how we know it's infinitesimal just because it's continuous. Sorry if this is an obvious question.

Comment: In the context of nonstandard analysis, this is usually the _definition_ of continuity (or more properly, uniform continuity, but it doesn't make a difference in this context).  A function $f$ is (uniformly) continuous iff whenever $x$ is infinitely close to $y$, $f(x)$ is infinitely close to $f(y)$.

Comment: now if a function is not uniformly continuous like $x^2$ as I have been reading, doesn't this change things a bit? You said it doesnt matter in this context though, so maybe I'm misunderstanding. Because as x increases by an infinitesimal we can't guarantee that the function will increase by an infinitesimal? Or am I misunderstanding uniform continuity

Comment: @rb612, the relation between uniform continuity and infinitesimals is an interesting topic in its own right. You might want to ask a separate question. Leave a *comment* for me if you do so.

Comment: @rb612: You only need uniform continuity when restricted to $[0,1]$, and any continuous function on $[0,1]$ (or any other compact domain) is automatically uniformaly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Let's compute!

Suppose we integrate $\int_0^1 x \, \mathrm{d}x$ by pick a Riemann sum with $H$ equally sized intervals.

The smallest and largest value of $x$ in the $i$-th interval is $\frac{i-1}{H}$ and $\frac{i}{H}$ respectively, and that interval would contribute $\frac{i-1}{H} \cdot \frac{1}{H}$ and $\frac{i}{H} \cdot \frac{1}{H}$ respectively to the total sum, so the maximum possible error from ths interval is $\frac{1}{H^2}$.

However, there are only $H$ intervals — the error therefore cannot be any larger than $\frac{1}{H^2} \cdot H = \frac{1}{H}$, an infinitesimal.

And for fun,we compute the integral using the upper bounds:
$$ \begin{align*}
\int_0^1 x \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \text{std} \sum_{i=1}^H \left( \frac{i}{H} \right) \cdot \frac{1}{H}
\\&= \text{std} \left( \frac{1}{H^2} \sum_{i=1}^H i \right)
\\&= \text{std} \left( \frac{1}{H^2} \frac{H(H+1)}{2} \right)
\\&= \text{std} \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2H} \right)
\\&= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
$$

You can see how the errors of